# drawing an image inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

the code :

```
function DrawLevel1() {
    Pos = 1;
    w = 84;
    h = 84;
    x = 28;
    y = 28;
    for (i = 0; i < cw; i += 28) {   /// use +=

        ctx.drawImage(tankImg,
                  (Pos - 1) * w, /// x of source (use 0-based indexes)
                   0,            /// y of source
                   w,            /// width of source
                   h,            /// height of source
                   i,            /// x in destination (visible canvas)
                   y,            /// y, width and height of the resulting
                   w, h);        /// image
        x += 28;
        y += 28;
    }
}
```

DrawLevel1();

image :

[image: http://oi62.tinypic.com/148yf7.jpg]

canvas: `<canvas id="MyCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>`

what i am trying to do basically is drawing the first grey tiles all along the first row of the  width of the canvas `cw` .notice that i can't use a tiled array and draw it ,this function is not drawing anything and i can't figure out why can anyone help me please
jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/B2nUs/36/

Comment: use `i += 28` instead of `i + 28` in your loop.

Comment: I don't see where `cw` is defined, and it's the exit condition for your loop. This seems important. You're also not incrementing `i` in your loop - how about `i+=28` (or the longer form, `i=i+28`)

Comment: i updated my code please check the fiddle it's not drawing anything

Comment: lol kind of yeah !!!please can u tell me why this function isn't working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modify your code and this is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yalight/5cHQF/

```
function DrawLevel1() {
    Pos = 1;
    w = 84;
    h = 84;
    x = 28;
    y = 28;
    for (i = 0; i < cw; i += 28) {   /// use +=
        for(j = 0; j< cw; j += 28) {

            ctx.drawImage(tankImg,
                   0, /// x of source (use 0-based indexes)
                   0,            /// y of source
                   w,            /// width of source
                   h,            /// height of source
                   i,            /// x in destination (visible canvas)
                   j,            /// y, width and height of the resulting
                   w, h);        /// image
            x += 28;
            y += 28;
        }
    }
}
```

Only draw first row http://jsfiddle.net/yalight/FT8M2/ :

```
function DrawLevel1() {
    w = 84;
    h = 84;
    x = 28;
    //y = 28;
    for (i = 0; i < cw; i += x) {   /// use +=
        ctx.drawImage(tankImg,
            0,     /// x of source (use 0-based indexes)
            0,     /// y of source
            w,     /// width of source
            h,     /// height of source
            i,     /// x in destination (visible canvas)
            0,     /// y, width and height of the resulting
            w, h); /// image
    }
}
```

And you should call DrawLevel1 in here:

```
function Draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    DrawLevel1(); // here
    PlayerTank.draw();
    Missiles.draw();
    Enemies.draw();
}
```

Comment: but this is not what i am aiming for i just need to draw the grey tiles in the first row of the canvas

Comment: OK, I've changed it to draw the first row only! http://jsfiddle.net/yalight/FT8M2/